# show text on hover (React)

Tags: reactjs, hover

I have two divs and I want them to show the text on hover, but when I hover over one of them they both show the text.
Here is the code:

```
>     const [text, setText] = useState(0);
>     <div onMouseEnter={e=> setText(1)} onMouseLeave={e=> setText(0)}>
>         <h1>hover the div to show the text</h1>
>         <p style={{opacity: `${text}`}}>some dummy text</p>
>     </div>
      <div onMouseEnter={e=> setText(1)} onMouseLeave={e=> setText(0)}>
>         <h1>hover the div to show the text</h1>
>         <p style={{opacity: `${text}`}}>some dummy text</p>
>     </div>
```

Comment: Because both divs are bound to the same state `text`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it, here is the code:

```
 const [text, setText] = useState({firstDiv:0, secondDiv: 0});
 <div onMouseEnter={e=> setText({firstDiv:1, secondDiv: 0})} onMouseLeave={e=> setText(0)}>
     <h1>hover the div to show the text</h1>
     <p style={{opacity: text.firstDiv}}>some dummy text</p>
 </div>
  <div onMouseEnter={e=> setText({firstDiv:0, secondDiv: 1})} onMouseLeave={e=> setText(0)}>
     <h1>hover the div to show the text</h1>
     <p style={{opacity: text.secondDiv}}>some dummy text</p>
 </div>
```